# Practicality of driving LEDs with high voltage?

Tags: led, switch-mode-power-supply, constant-current

After watching someone build a fairly wasteful project, I wondered if there was a better way. The LEDs are cheap chinese variety, with a forward voltage of around 34-36V @3A, and they throw off about 10,000 lumens. They used a SMPS, putting out 24V, and a cheap boost converter to get upto 36V. For each of 10 LEDs. I thought that was a pretty crappy way to drive 10 of these, an expensive at that.

The way I would do it, is with one large SMPS at a common and cheap voltage, like 24V, and step up the voltage to 360V and control the leds with current. Is this a practical approach? I see a lot of chips to control LEDs at 350mA, but not a lot for 3A. Are there design limitations I'm not considering? I've done some HV stuff, but it was just a plasma speaker.

Comment: Can you clarify your requirements? What I am taking away from your question is that the crappy implementation had 10 loads, each with an individual 300 mA driver. You are wondering if it would be OK to put the 10 loads in parallel and drive with 3A. Is that right? Oh, nevermind. Sorry for the poor comprehension. It seems that you want to put 10 loads in series, and drive at 3A, 360V (approx). Is that correct?

Comment: Sorry for the terrible question. I would be putting 10 of these LEDs in series. The crappy implementation was driven at 3A, not 300ma. I wouldn't be putting the LEDs in parallel. However, I would be driving them at a constant current, 3A. Your last statement is correct.

Answer (score 2):

So you want to make a 24V->360V controlled current SMPS that can supply more than 1kW? I don't think that's a very easy project to start with. At 24V you're going to be dealing with almost 50A of current. If it was an off-line switcher the currents would be lower, but a 1kW supply is still going to be a challenge.

You don't mention the topology you have in mind for the step-up, but I doubt a simple boost converter will be practical- you'll probably need a transformer-based forward converter or other high power topology. In which case you might as well do an off-line switcher.

If you really want to run the LEDs at 360V, there will be a serious lethal shock hazard- probably more than 400VDC at substantial current if the circuit is broken.

It might be practical to fool an off-the-shelf 100W 36V (nominal) supply into supplying constant current by diddling the trim input with an op-amp, but you'd need 10 of them. On the plus side, a single supply or LED failure won't take out the whole lot.

Or a fixed (say) 48V supply and 10 individual buck converters (which would only require inductors).

However this is done, to get constant current to 10 different LEDs with a total of more than 1kW power is not going to be really cheap or simple if its done properly.

Comment: It's recommended that a "simple" boost converter shouldn't have a  boost factor greater than 5 or 6.  Otherwise, there are stability problems.  So, going from 24V to 360V with a single stage boost is not a good idea.

Comment: By "diddling the trim input with an op-amp" what do you mean? Could you break it down, or even just point me to a website with a tutorial/build log?

Comment: The details would depend on the way trim input works .. Basically detect the current with a resistor, subtract from the desired current and feed the error to the trim input.